# Angular 2 observable issue

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I am trying to get data on the basis of id which is set in url

working on add mode but getting error for edit

```
   export class GradeComponent implements OnInit {

  public isNew:boolean=true;
  public frmGrade: FormGroup;
  public subscription:any;
  public oldGrade:Grade;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder ,
    private gradeService:GradeService,
    private router:Router,
    private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute
  ) { }


 ngOnInit() {
    if(typeof this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] ==='undefined'){
      this.frmGrade = this.formBuilder.group({
        grade: ['', Validators.required],
        description: ''
      });
    }else{
      this.setForUpdate();
    }
  }

  private setForUpdate(){
      this.isNew=false;
      this.gradeService
            .getOneGrade(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'])
            .subscribe(
                data => { 
                  this.oldGrade = data,
                    this.frmGrade = this.formBuilder.group({
                      grade: [this.oldGrade.grade, Validators.required],
                      description: this.oldGrade.description
                    });
                },
                err => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('done')
              );
  }
```

but i am getting error 
this.formBuilder is undefined how to handle this .

Comment: `this.formBuilder` doesn't come out of nowhere ;-) Why do you think it should be there?

Comment: for updating record, i want to get old data from id and then assign to frm

Comment: What form? . . .. .

Comment: frmGrade frmbuilder

Comment: Please show more code.

Answer (score 1):

FormBuilder is a service Injectable, just get an instance with Dependancy Injection.

Add this in your class:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
```

And you are ready to go.

Comment: If you don't provide us the whole code, we can't guess it. Be complete in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 export class GradeComponent implements OnInit {

  public isNew:boolean=true;
  public frmGrade: FormGroup;
  public subscription:any;
  public oldGrade:Grade;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder ,
    private gradeService:GradeService,
    private router:Router,
    private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute
  ) { }


 ngOnInit() {

   this.frmGrade = this.formBuilder.group({
        grade: ['', Validators.required],
        description: ''
      });

   if(typeof this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] !=='undefined')  {
    this.setForUpdate();  

    }
  }

  private setForUpdate(){
      this.isNew=false;
      this.gradeService
            .getOneGrade(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'])
            .subscribe(
                data => { 
                  this.oldGrade = data,
                    this.frmGrade = this.formBuilder.group({
                      grade: [this.oldGrade.grade, Validators.required],
                      description: this.oldGrade.description
                    });
                },
                err => console.error(err),
                () => console.log('done')
              );
  }
```